# How to extract xml attribute using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python

I am trying to extract xml attribute using Python ElementTree as below ,however `destinationmilestone.attrib['key']` doesn't give the values `event3,event4`instead it prints the keys `milestone1,milestone2`,what am I doing wrong?I have the current output and expected output below for clarity

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('seed.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

destination_milestone_event_dict={}
events = []
radar_event = 'event1'

for milestone in root.findall('milestone'):
    #print milestone
    if milestone.get('name') == 'Internal Tools - milestone4':
        seed_cloning = milestone.find('seed_cloning')
        if seed_cloning != None:
            #print "In seed cloning"
            events = seed_cloning.find('events').text.split(',')
            #print events
            if radar_event in events:
                #create destination_milestone_event_dict 
                destinationmilestones = seed_cloning.findall('destinationmilestone')
                for destinationmilestone in  destinationmilestones:
                    key = destinationmilestone.get('key')
                    print key
                    value = destinationmilestone.attrib['key']
                    print value
                    destination_milestone_event_dict[key] = value
                print destination_milestone_event_dict
```

seed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<milestones>
    <milestone name="milestone">
        <destination_milestones>milestone3</destination_milestones>
        <cross_os_cloning>
            <destinationmilestones>milestone2 Candidate</destinationmilestones>
            <shared_projects>tech-ci,Core</shared_projects>
        </cross_os_cloning>
    </milestone>
    <milestone name="Internal Tools - milestone4">
        <destination_milestones>milestone3</destination_milestones>
        <seed_cloning>
            <events>event1,event2</events>
            <destinationmilestone key="milestone1">event3</destinationmilestone>
            <destinationmilestone key="milestone2">event4</destinationmilestone>.
        </seed_cloning>
    </milestone>
</milestones>
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
milestone1
milestone1
milestone2
milestone2
{'milestone1': 'milestone1', 'milestone2': 'milestone2'}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
milestone1
event3
milestone2
event4
{'milestone1': 'event3', 'milestone2': 'event4'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.text` to get the value (contents of the tag):

```
value = destinationmilestone.text
```